# DDNS Hostname Address?

Tags: applications

Probably a dumb question...

I have a ddns that I got through no-ip.com. I have everything all set up in PuTty on my computer using the username.no-ip.org (and the port number in a different spot).

I downloaded Connectbot for Android, and it's asking me for username@hostname:port. I tried username@no-ip.org:1234 (left out real username and port for security reasons). I can't connect. How do I "convert" my ddns address to be in the format as required by Connectbot?

I know I'm missing something simple... a while ago I had this set up and working. But now I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just needed it to be root@username.no-ip.org:1234.